# Optimization rule for variables

Tags: arangodb

I'm observing a huge difference in query performance between these two statements:

```
FOR w IN relatedAffils
    COLLECT from = w._from, to = w._to INTO agg
    INSERT { "_from": from, "_to": to, "weight": LENGTH(agg), 
       "fromAff": DOCUMENT(from).affiliation
       } INTO relatedAffilsAggregated
```

and

```
FOR w IN relatedAffils
    COLLECT from = w._from, to = w._to INTO agg

    LET fromDoc = DOCUMENT(from)

    INSERT { "_from": from, "_to": to, "weight": LENGTH(agg), 
       "fromAff": fromDoc.affiliation
       } INTO relatedAffilsAggregated
```

The latter takes more than five times longer than the first one (> 30 minutes for two million records). Maybe this is because in the second version I'm using temporary variables. Maybe this is a point where another optimization rule could make sense?

Another example:

```
FOR w IN relatedAffilsAggregated

    FILTER DOCUMENT(w._from).country == "deu"
    FILTER DOCUMENT(w._to).affiliation < DOCUMENT(w._from).affiliation

    SORT w.weight DESC

    LIMIT 1000


    RETURN CONCAT( w.weight, ":  (", DOCUMENT(w._from).country, ",", `DOCUMENT(w._to).country, ") ", DOCUMENT(w._from).affiliation, " <----> ", DOCUMENT(w._to).affiliation)`
```

Needs about 30 seconds, whereas I killed the alternative using variables after 30 minutes.

```
FOR w IN relatedAffilsAggregated

    LET fromDoc = DOCUMENT(w._from)
    FILTER fromDoc.country == "deu"

    LET toDoc = DOCUMENT(w._to)
    FILTER fromDoc.affiliation < toDoc.affiliation

    SORT w.weight DESC

    LIMIT 1000

    RETURN CONCAT( w.weight, ":  (", fromDoc.country, ",", toDoc.country, ") ", fromDoc.affiliation, " <----> ", toDoc.affiliation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first query will execute one calculation less than the second query.

In the first query, the `DOCUMENT(from).affiliation` will be calculated together with the to-be-inserted object.

In the second query, there is an extra calculation for `fromDoc`, and the contents of this variable will be carried around in the query, into the `INSERT`.

The second query can be made a bit more efficient by rewriting the `LET` declaration as follows:

```
LET fromDoc = DOCUMENT(from).affiliation
```

and by using just `fromDoc` instead of `fromDoc.affiliation` in the `INSERT`. This will reduce the amount of data in the `fromDoc` variable from entire documents to just one attribute.

Another thing is that using the `INTO agg` is quite expensive in both queries. All that's needed from `agg` is its length, so the `INTO` clause may be changed into:

```
INTO agg = 1
```

This will again reduce the amount of data inside `agg` to a simple number instead of full documents. This syntax is available since 2.4.

Auto-detection of the above things and auto-transformation of the query would be nice. Possibly a transformation that merges multiple calculations into one would help.

Comment: I agree with your comments. Unfortunately they only work due to the point that I tried to simplify/generalize my example. I'll add another one with an impressive difference of execution time. Maybe that brings it better to the point.

Comment: So, is it typical that direct usage of document attributes where needed (even in multiple places) is much more efficient than storing the document in a LET variable first and than re-using this?